# ns3 sendstuff cause memory increase

Tags: c++, ns-3

I have a question about ns3.
We create 250 nodes in first kvm using csma，and communicate to another kvm（through router）by using tap bridge and udp socket.
But when we started running the program，use linux command "top" to see memory utilization, it will be increasing; and when we output the `m_unscheduledEvents`，the ++ is much more than --，that means the `SendStuff()` is increasing.
And how can we solve the memory increasing question？

Here is the `SendStuff()` function：

```
void SendStuff (Ptr<Socket> sock, Ipv4Address dstaddr, uint16_t port)
{
  uint8_t fill1[376]={...};;
  Ptr<Packet> p = Create<Packet> (fill1, 376);
  sock->SendTo (p, 0, InetSocketAddress (dstaddr,port));
  unsigned int dest_IP;
  dest_IP = start_ip + rand()%(range+1);
  Simulator::Schedule (Seconds(scan_interval), &SendStuff, sock, Ipv4Address(dest_IP), port);
  return;
}
```

And when we receive a packet we call this function and constantly send packets:

```
Simulator::Schedule (Seconds(scan_interval), &SendStuff, socket, Ipv4Address(dest_IP), scan_port);
```

PS: when we increasing `scan_interval` memory growth will slow down. When we expand the size of the network node（the dest_IP range will be larger). Memory growth will be faster...

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you have to destroy your packet after sending to get rid of your mem leak.